# Markings on a 3ml syringe

Tags: injections, measurement, apothecary, med-symbol-abbreviations

I have some 3ml syringes with 23Gx1" needles. But there is also a second scale on the syringe that is marked as "M" and 40M is right at around the 2.5 ml measure. What is this M scale mean? I thought it might be IU but the numbers wouldn't be right.

Comment: Could you possibly get a picture? I think that would be helpful here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Minim (unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(unit)): Part of the Apothecary system. It is rarely used anymore(some countries and areas still use the apothecary system) and is a alternative to the drop(which was formerly the smallest unit of the apothecary system).

> The minim (abbreviated min, ♏ or Mx, a symbol for minim in the
>   apothecaries' system.svg) is a unit of volume in both the imperial and
>   US customary systems of measurement. Specifically it is 1⁄60 of a
>   fluidram[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(unit)) or 1⁄480 of a fluid ounce.

40 minim are equal to 2.48 ml. Varying slightly on [what kind of calculator](http://www.theunitconverter.com/volume-conversion/) you use.

[Henke's Med-Math: Dosage Calculation, Preparation and Administration](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZlKqGHGNrtIC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=M%20syringe%20marking%20on%203%20ml%20syringe&source=bl&ots=8v6urPntOb&sig=bYfwYKp64yqnyzNNudNzQpgfOnE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8hNL_3eTLAhVjtYMKHYJyCakQ6AEIVzAN#v=onepage&q=M%20syringe%20marking%20on%203%20ml%20syringe&f=false)

Since its a Injection you would round the number to the nearest 10th, so 2.46 or 2.48 would become 2.5ml's.

Minim: [medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/minim)

There appear to be a few types of the minim. For this, I only chose the calculation for the mimim that plainly said Minim, there appear to be a imperial and US or UK version of the Minim.

Picture courtesy of [cwladis.com](http://www.cwladis.com/math104/lecture3.php)

[image]

Comment: The calculations make sense, this must be it - thank you